# Comment traduire « I know, right » ?

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

Ça veut dire qu’on est vachement d’accord avec ce qu’a dit l’autre personne.

ex.

> - That new horror movie is so damn good.
> - I know, right?

J’ai vu utiliser « T’as vu ! » Est-ce que ça serait la bonne traduction ? Sinon comment est-ce que cette expression est utilisée ?

Comment: `T'as vu` is all over the place : often `oui hein, t'as vu ?`

Comment: Also `j'avoue !` borrowed from teen speech.

Comment: [« Vachement »](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vachement+d%27accord%2Cvachement%2Cvachement+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvachement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cvachement%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvachement%20bien%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvachement%20important%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvachement%20sympa%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvachement%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvachement%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvachement%20bon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvachement%20chouette%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvachement%20mal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvachement%20dur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvachement%20en%3B%2Cc0) ne convient pas avec « d'accord ».

Answer (score 3):

May be:

- Je veux !
- C'est clair !
- Putain, ouais !

Comment: Et aussi : trop, carrément, trop clair, tu m'étonnes...